# Google analytics for Flask doesn't track the page view information

Tags: python, flask, google-analytics

I've been playing around with GA (Google-Analytics) and I can't get it to track the page view I am triggering an event in.

**Background**

I am not using any fancy 3rd party library for this; I only post a json object with the things I need to be tracked, following the steps provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/integrating-with-analytics):

The connection between my Flask app and their API works, since I get 1 user connected in my GA dashboard while navigating through my website.

The outcome I need to achieve is once I navigate to a route, say `127.0.0.1/projects`, I want that route to be shown in my `Real-Time/Overview/Top Activate Pages`.

[image]

**Code**

In my `utils.py` I have a function called `track_event` which is being imported anytime I need it

```
''' Google analytics tracking function. '''
def track_event(event, category, action, label=None, value=0):
    data = {
        'v': '1',  # API Version.
        'tid': current_app.config['GA_TRACKING_ID'],  # Tracking ID / Property ID.
        # Anonymous Client Identifier. Ideally, this should be a UUID that
        # is associated with particular user, device, or browser instance.
        'cid': '555',
        't': event,  # Event hit type.
        'ec': category,  # Event category.
        'ea': action,  # Event action.
        'el': label,  # Event label.
        'ev': value,  # Event value, must be an integer
        'ua': 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14'
    }

    print(data)

    response = requests.post(
        'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', data=data)

    print(response.raise_for_status)
    
    # If the request fails, this will raise a RequestException. Depending
    # on your application's needs, this may e a non-error and can be caught by
    # the caller.
    response.raise_for_status()
```

- Route that imports the tracking function *

```
''' Route of dynamically generated post. '''
@bp.route('/projects/post/<post_id>')
def post(post_id):
    track_event(event=f'/projects/post/{post_id}',category='Projects', action=f'post triggered {post_id}')
    # some more code
    return render_template('post.html', title=f'Project {post_id}', project=project, images=images)
```

By looking at [GA collection parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ds), the parameter `t` should be the one I m interested in:

> Required for all hit types. The type of hit. Must be one of 'pageview', 'screenview', 'event', 'transaction', 'item', 'social', 'exception', 'timing'.

Even with that, nothing shows up in the dashboard aforementioned. Any tips or hints would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to use the [gtag.js client library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs).

You would put this in the head tag of your global HTML template (swapping in your `GA_MEASUREMENT_ID`).

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

It will automatically capture page views unless you explicitly turn them off by specifying:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { 'send_page_view': false });
```

Comment: Very fast implementation. Is this way so safe and flexible as the first mentioned in the question?